# Unable to start VSCode as root on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, vscode-remote

I have VSCode 1.79.2 running on Ubuntu 20.04 which I installed using snap. When I try to start VSCode as root using the following command:

sudo code --verbose --user-data-dir=/root/.config/Code --no-sandbox

I just get a blank dialog as shown in the attachment below.
[image]

I am also attaching my logs.
[image]

Logs

```
[9777:0620/002407.015879:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[9777:0620/002407.016217:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
[9777:0620/002407.044186:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
[9802:0620/002407.050645:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
ERR: DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
[9802:0620/002407.051043:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:1004 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Not initialized.
ERR: Display.cpp:1004 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Not initialized.
[9802:0620/002407.051300:ERROR:gl_display.cc(508)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Not initialized.
[9802:0620/002407.051518:ERROR:gl_display.cc(920)] eglInitialize SwANGLE failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[9802:0620/002407.051740:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(23)] GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[9802:0620/002407.055340:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
[9816:0620/002407.099533:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
ERR: DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
[9816:0620/002407.099823:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:1004 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Not initialized.
ERR: Display.cpp:1004 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Not initialized.
[9816:0620/002407.099997:ERROR:gl_display.cc(508)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Not initialized.
[9816:0620/002407.100132:ERROR:gl_display.cc(920)] eglInitialize SwANGLE failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[9816:0620/002407.100276:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(23)] GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[9816:0620/002407.103936:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
[9823:0620/002407.173086:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
ERR: DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
```

Any help would be extremely grateful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me:

```
sudo code --user-data-dir=/root/.config/Code --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox
```

I got this solution from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184687#issuecomment-1599664177